# No audio in alarm or timer with Clocks Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, gnome-clocks

When I set an alarm (or set a timer) in Clocks in Ubuntu 20.04, the alarm clearly triggers as at the appropriate moment a notification appears at the top of the screen and I get a message in the Clocks application asking me to stop or snooze; however this is all silent - I get no audio alarm. I have another laptop still running 18.04 and the audio for these alarms works fine on that.

On my 20.04 machine, audio is functioning fine in other applications. I've checked that notifications are on. The Notifications settings in Settings for Clocks has notifications, sound alerts, notification popups and even lock screen notifications on. When in Settings I check Applications, GNOME Clocks has notifications on, too. In the sound panel, system sounds are on and they are turned up, and when I test the alert sound buttons I get an appropriate noise.

The version of Clocks is just the one that comes installed on the machine (ubuntu-focal-updates-universe), rather than a Snap or some such thing.

Could there be something I'm missing? Or might there be a bug in Clocks 3.36.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to look into this further and think I can answer my own question now. There is a current bug report for this problem:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-clocks/+bug/1878361
It seems to have been due to an update on a  dependency called vala, and this appears to have been fixed, so hopefully a functioning version will be released in an update soon.

Comment: Just over 3 months have passed but I still have the same problem - i.e. my Gnome-clock (Ubuntu 20.04) does not sound (despite the audio of my pc being fine).